# Twig Extract author

Tags: symfony, twig, facebook-opengraph

Within my Twig view I have

```
{% do headmeta().appendName('author', 'Ron Piggott') %}
```

I am wondering if I am able to extract this within the Twig layout.  The following doesn't work, it shows what I am trying to do:

```
{{ headMeta().author }}
```

What I am trying to do is create the og tag, similar to

```
{{ headTitle()|replace({'<title>': '<meta property="og:title" content="', '</title>': '" />'})|raw }}
```

Comment: It looks like totally nonsense to me. Remember that twig is made to render the output and not for your program logic. That should be done in the controller and your services.

Comment: It seems that you use extension functions headMeta, headTitle. You should look at the source of those extensions to see what you can do with them. If you do so you will see where those functions get data from (i.e. author, title, etc...)